# Return() from functions - I'm doing it wrong?

Tags: python, return-value

I'm trying to walk a directory, retrieve all files within that directory ending with a certain extension, and write that file to a list. This is list is supposed to be returned after the function is done doing its job.

```
def grabFiles(source,ext):
    import fnmatch
    import os

    matches = [] #tmp var which is used to return the files matching the search mask.
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source):   #for each folder & subfolder do:
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, ext): #and for each file found like that do:
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))#append the file name&directory to the "matches" variable.
    return(matches) #return the content of matches
```

Now when I run this using the following:

```
ext=[".caf", ".lmg", ".chr", ".cdf", ".dds", ".tif", ".mtl", ".cgf", ".cga"]

for filetype in ext:
     files= nPy.grabFiles("D:\\01_SVN\\01_DE\\trunk\\Game",filetype)
     print files
```

I believe it should be returning me a list with files for each extension in my ext list, right?
Instead it returns a [ ] for each item in the ext list.

If I fire this thing without using a definition, it works just fine :/

```
import fnmatch
import os
source ="D:\\01_SVN\\01_DE\\trunk\\Game"  
extension = ["*.mtl","*.tif","*.chr"] 
matches = []
for filetype in extension:
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("%s" % (source)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, "%s" % (filetype)):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
print matches
```

I've been staring at this for over an hour, and Im afraid im practically blind to my own script by now :< Im either incapable of returning a dang list, or Im  misunderstanding how returning works - but it should be passing the list from matches to a new var without a problem, no?

Comment: Just a note: It's a really bad idea to import inside a function - do it at the start of the module.

Comment: noted, thx for the heads up :)

Comment: Whats the reason that you keep doing string formatting with only a single string argument? Why not just use that single string variable?

Comment: Another note: `return` is not a function, so using `()` around its argument is quite odd. I know some folks do it, but I never understood why, so I think it's worth pointing out just so you can reflect on it.

Comment: @unwind: Its kind of like wanting to return a tuple, but even with a tuple return type, you don't need `()` since its implied, so yes, its not necc for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are matching `.ext` instead of `*.ext`. Try adding the star to match the name and it should work.

```
def grabFiles(source,ext):
    import fnmatch
    import os

    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*' + ext):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return matches
```

About you programming style:

- avoid repeating what you are doing in comments. It is useless
- return is a keyword like print, not a function
- I would use `endswith` rather that fnmatch.filter
- avoid importing in functions
- instead of `source ="D:\\01_SVN\\01_DE\\trunk\\Game"` use `source=r"D:\01_SVN\01_DE\trunk\Game"`

Comment: @NilsDiefenbach No pb :-). So the answer is "yes, you are doing it slightly wrong, but that is not the issue". Don't forget to accept.